# How do I convert unity shader to URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shaderlab, urp

So I found this shader on the internet, but apparently it doesn't work with URP, what do I add to it to make it work with URP? I don't know much about shaders. Kindly help me out.

```
Shader "Custom/Auto Tiling" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Scale("Texture Scale", Float) = 1.0
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Lambert

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    fixed4 _Color;
    float _Scale;

    struct Input {
        float3 worldNormal;
        float3 worldPos;
    };

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
        float2 UV;
        fixed4 c;

        if (abs(IN.worldNormal.x) > 0.5) {
            UV = IN.worldPos.yz; // side
            c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use WALLSIDE texture
        }
        else if (abs(IN.worldNormal.z) > 0.5) {
            UV = IN.worldPos.xy; // front
            c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use WALL texture
        }
        else {
            UV = IN.worldPos.xz; // top
            c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use FLR texture
        }

        o.Albedo = c.rgb * _Color;
    }
    ENDCG
}

Fallback "Legacy Shaders/VertexLit"
```

}